Problem command and tikzcd
When I compile this
 $$ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep={small},nodes={inner sep=2pt}]
 {| +1 \rangle} & {\langle +2|} \\
{\langle +3 |} & {| +4 \rangle}
\arrow[no head, from=1-1, to=2-2]
\arrow[no head, from=1-2, to=2-1]
\end{tikzcd} $$

it works perfectly. But when I define a command like this (note that I made a search and replace in the code above with #-->+ to keep all the text exactly the same)
\newcommand{\tfour}[4]{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={small},nodes={inner sep=2pt}]
 {| #1 \rangle} & {\langle #2|} \\
{\langle #3 |} & {| #4 \rangle}
\arrow[no head, from=1-1, to=2-2]
\arrow[no head, from=1-2, to=2-1]
\end{tikzcd}}

and use
$$\tfour{a}{b}{c}{d} $$

I get 101 errors, starting with

Undefined control sequence

What is the problem? I just want to define a command that is the same commutative diagram all the time changing the text in the nodes.
Also, if I want to use \left \right in the command I get different errors. What is the proper way to use them in a command?
My preamble is this
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools,mathrsfs,bm}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}% xcolor>color
\definecolor{colordelink}{rgb}{0,0,0.50}
\definecolor{colordecite}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{colordeurl}{rgb}{0,0.41,0.5}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=colordelink,
citecolor=colordecite,
    urlcolor=colordeurl,
    }

\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\usepackage{todonotes}



\input{Style-and-more}

And in Style-and-more I have my command.

Welcome back to TeX.SE. Please provide a complete minimal document with a documentclass, usepackages etc. This makes it easier to reproduce the problem and to test potential solutions.

@Marijn is this ok?

it is better, but not really ideal. There are a lot of packages that are unrelated to the question, the structure with the input can be simplified, \begin{document} and \end{document} are missing, and the command that you define is not called in the code. The goal is not to show a closely as possible what your setup is, the goal is to make it as easy as possible to reproduce the problem and to start to solve it. Now egreg had to do the simplification and boilerplate himself, which is unnecessary work for him and it runs the risk that it does not match your actual problem

although here it seems fine. So for any future questions it would be nice if your code would look like the code in egregs answer, as short as possible, but compilable as it is - and of course in the non-working version without the part that actually solves the issue.

@Marijn Understood, thanks.

tikz-cd wants to see explicit & in its body (where it becomes an active character). Whenever tikz-cd appears in the argument to another command (including \newcommand) you have to use ampersand replacement.
I made a few more fixes: \lvert or \rvert instead of |, so braces aren't necessary (and the spacing will be right).
Also $$ should never be used in a LaTeX document environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\tfour}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    column sep=small,
    nodes={inner sep=2pt},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
  ]
  \lvert #1 \rangle \& \langle #2\rvert \\
  \langle #3 \rvert \& \lvert #4 \rangle
  \arrow[no head, from=1-1, to=2-2]
  \arrow[no head, from=1-2, to=2-1]
  \end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\tfour{a}{b}{c}{d}
\]

\end{document}



Thank you. Why shouldn't I use double dollar? I read that it only makes a different spacing than other equation environments. Is there another reason?

@MathBug mostly spacing, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to
